# Chrome search engines – change on the fly

Tags: google-chrome, search

I would like to change search engine based on search term nature.

So for term “new shoes” I would like to use [Bing](https://www.bing.com/) and for “WW2” I would like to use [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org).

How can this be achieved in **Google Chrome** like it can be simply done in **Firefox** for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from search bar. You just need to know keywords assigned to search engine you need. To know the keyword, right click on search bar and select `Edit Search Engines...` from menu. Look for the keyword columns of available search engines.

[image]

Now, if you need to change search engine on the fly, just type keyword and press `TAB` key. You will see the change in search engine. Now, you can type your search string.

For example, in my case I types `bing` and pressed `TAB` key.

[image]

**Update:** 
Based on comments, i came up with one beautiful solution :D
Here are steps:

1. Install `AutoHotKey` (This is free).
2. Create following script. In my case this script is for `bing`. More such scripts can be added.

[image]

3. Save the script with `.ahk` extension. Double click on it to run it with `AutoHotKey`
4. Open `Chrome` browser, click on search bar and press `CTRL` + `ALT` + `B`. This will send `BING + TAB` key to `chrome` and search engine will change to `bing`.

In `AutoHotKey` `^` is `CTRL`, `!` is `ALT`. So, `^!b` means when you press `CTRL + ALT + B` key combination, `AutoHotKey` will send keys `BING + TAB` to chrome or any window in focus. Here `bing` is `keyword` of search engine.

Comment: That’s weird ugly solution but works good.